# Бесконечная галерея

Tags: jquery, metro, php, gallery, css

доброе время суток. не нашёл / *либо плохо искал* / галерею, которую можно прокручивать без конца, хотя таких куча. не знаю название самого оформления, чтобы картинки располагались заполняя пустоты, в зависимости от размера (метро?!)

Comment: пример: http://i62.tinypic.com/209q7wl.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://masonry.desandro.com/ такое вам подойдет?